# Make a subgraph of a boost graph by removing leaves

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-graph

I have a BGL graph, of type vecS. I want to make a new graph of it by removing leaves. I need it mainly for visulization, becasue there are a lot of leaves that I don't need to visualize. According to this post [c++ remove vertex from a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210669/c-remove-vertex-from-a-graph)
and [BGL page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) removing vertices from a vecS adjacencylist is not safe. So what is the solution in my case that I have a vecS graph? How I may make a new graph without leaves.

```
    /// vertex properties
struct VertexData
{
    std::string label;
    int num;
    bool is_leaf=false;
};

/// edges properties
struct EdgeData
{
    std::string edge_name;
    double edge_confidence;
};

/// define the boost-graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t , size_t , VertexData>,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, EdgeData> > Graph;
```

Thanks for your answer.

PS. Is it possible to use a `predicate` and [filtered_graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/filtered_graph.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit surprising that you have a boolean flag to indicate what is a leaf. In the nature of graphs it would seem logical to assume a leaf is any vertex with out-degree of 0.

Regardless:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41150b8332e96f8b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

/// vertex properties
struct VertexData {
    std::string label;
    int num;
    bool is_leaf=false;
};

/// edges properties
struct EdgeData {
    std::string edge_name;
    double edge_confidence;
};

/// define the boost-graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, size_t, VertexData>,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, EdgeData> > Graph;

using Predicate = std::function<bool(Graph::vertex_descriptor)>;
using Filtered  = boost::filtered_graph<Graph, boost::keep_all, Predicate>;

Graph make_graph();

int main() {
    Graph g = make_graph();
    auto const labels = get(&VertexData::label, g);

    std::cout << "\n---Main graph:\n";
    print_graph(g, labels);

    // manual markings
    {
        auto manual_is_leaf = [&g](Graph::vertex_descriptor vd) { return !g[vd].is_leaf; };
        Filtered manual(g, boost::keep_all{}, manual_is_leaf);

        {

            std::cout << "\n---Filtered, no leafs:\n";
            print_graph(manual, labels);
        }

        {
            std::cout << "\n---Filtered, manual leafs:\n";
            g[2].is_leaf = true; // only "three"

            print_graph(manual, labels);
        }
    }

    // automatic, dynamic markings
    {
        // note that for bidirectional/undirected out_degree might not make
        // sense, but neither does the notion of a leaf! 
        auto by_degree = [&g](Graph::vertex_descriptor vd) { return boost::out_degree(vd, g); };
        Filtered automatic(g, boost::keep_all{}, by_degree);

        {
            std::cout << "\n---Filtered by actual out_degree:\n";
            print_graph(automatic, labels);
        }

        {
            // make `five` and `six` appear:
            add_edge(5, 4, 100, g); // six -> five

            std::cout << "\n---After adding an edge:\n";
            print_graph(automatic, labels);
        }
    }
}

Graph make_graph() {
    Graph g;

    auto v1 = add_vertex({ 1, {"one",   100, false} }, g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex({ 2, {"two",   200, false} }, g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex({ 3, {"three", 300, false} }, g);
    auto v4 = add_vertex({ 4, {"four",  400, false} }, g);
    auto v5 = add_vertex({ 5, {"five",  500, false} }, g);
    auto v6 = add_vertex({ 6, {"six",   600, false} }, g);

    add_edge(v1, v2, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v2, v3, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v3, v4, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v3, v5, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v3, v6, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v2, v4, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v3, v5, 0.5, g);
    add_edge(v4, v6, 0.5, g);

    return g;
}
```

Prints

```
---Main graph:
one --> two 
two --> three four 
three --> four five six five 
four --> six 
five --> 
six --> 

---Filtered, no leafs:
one --> two 
two --> three four 
three --> four five six five 
four --> six 
five --> 
six --> 

---Filtered, manual leafs:
one --> two 
two --> four 
four --> six 
five --> 
six --> 

---Filtered by actual out_degree:
one --> two 
two --> three four 
three --> four 
four --> 

---After adding an edge:
one --> two 
two --> three four 
three --> four six 
four --> six 
six -->
```

> ### NOTE
>
> Replace `boost::out_degree` with `boost::degree` if you want to be more "true" to the nature of bidirectional/undirected graphs (see the comment). In that case you will see all vertices in the automatic section, because all vertices are connected with *some* edge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I use `is_leaf` flag, is that I have some not connected vertices which are not leaves but if I get their `out_degree` then it will be considered as leaf. I decided to use directedS, for time being to be able to use the automatic filtering in a safe way. Regardless that, I used the automatic code with modifying `return boost::out_degree(vd, g) != 0 ` and everything works as expected.

Comment: I have two IDE errors, the code compiles and results are correct but I have below errors from the IDE: 1. `using Predicate = std::function<bool(Graph::vertex_descriptor)>` error is `can't resolve struct member vertex_descriptor` and the second one is here: 2. `dp.property("label", get(&VertexData::label, automatic))` where dp is the  `dynamic property` I get the error: `can't resolve variable get` . Why I get these errors, and is it possible to use the new `filtered_graph` as an **exact filtered instance** of the original graph?